# Error found when call wallet creation method in ripple-lib as [RippledNotInitializedError(Rippled not initialized)]

Tags: ripple

I have used code as below

```
const api = new RippleAPI({
    //server: 'wss://s1.ripple.com' // Public rippled server
    server: 'ws://TestnetServerIp:6006' // testnet rippled server
});

router.get('/generateAddress', function (req, res) {
    api.connect().then(() => {
        return api.generateAddress();
    }).then(address => {
        console.log(" newly generated address is ", address);

        res.status(200).json(formatter.simpleFormat(address,true,"success"));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(formatter.simpleFormat(null,false,"error"));
    })
});
```

and got error while calling wallet creation API as

```
[RippledNotInitializedError(Rippled not initialized)]
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: [RippledNotInitializedError(Rippled not initialized)]
I got only this line on error while hit API of generateAddress

Answer (score -1):

Although this might not answer exactly what you're trying to achieve.

So I wouldn't suggest using `rippled` to generate new addresses and retrieving secret over whatever connection you have with your `rippled` server

Instead I'm suggesting you to use [ripple-keypairs](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-keypairs) to generate new address in offline environment. It should be fairly easy for you to do it by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

This means TestnetServerIp's server_state is not 'full'.

To check server_state, run this command:

```
rippled server_info 2>/dev/null | grep server_state
```

If the state is 'full', this command should output:

```
"server_state" : "full",
```

Normally, it should take only a couple of minutes before the state becomes 'full'.